# AngularJS select doesn't work properly on Iphone 14.6 Update

Tags: angularjs, angular, iphone, drop-down-menu

After 14.6 update on Iphone, select in angularjs is not working properly, sometimes i can select the value but most of the time it didn't update ng-model after selecting from dropdown and previously selected value didn't get updated by newly selected one.

Problem exists only in iphone 14.6 version on all browsers(Safari, chrome, brave)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
This problem was with angular-material

Tell the AngularJS Material Gesture module to skip (or ignore) click hijacking on mobile devices.

$mdGestureProvider.skipClickHijack();